# Is it possible to determine a time for sending alerts on the cloudwatch aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, alerts

Is it possible to determine a time for sending alerts on the cloudwatch aws?

For example:
I would like to configure the operation of alerts from **Monday** to **Friday** at **8 am** to **6 pm**

Answer (score 0):

A CloudWatch Alarm will trigger whenever the rule is met. It might take a minute or so to react (depending upon the metric and the aggregate function used).

However, it is **not possible to schedule *when* alerts operate**.

If you wish, you could create an **AWS Lambda function** (triggered on a schedule) that will call [`disable_alarm_actions()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.disable_alarm_actions) and [`enable_alarm_actions()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.enable_alarm_actions). The documentation says:

> `disable_alarm_actions()`: Disables the actions for the specified alarms. When an alarm's actions are disabled, the alarm actions do not execute when the alarm state changes.

Comment: John ,thank you so much!

It is a great solution, it will solve my problem.